# $(window).on('popstate') is not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, bootstrap-modal, back-button

`$window 'popstate'` event is not working in IE on browser back button. Below is the code snippet which is getting used to remove some modal classes on back button.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
    $('body').removeClass( 'modal-open' );
});
```

**Issue** - when Modal is open and on click of browser back button trying to remove modal classes on previous page which is coming after click of browser back button.

**In chrome it is working fine but in IE it's not going inside 'popstate'**
Any other way to remove classes on browser back button will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `hashchange` event instead on IE like:

```
function onHistoryChange(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  console.log('On History Change');
  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();
  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
}

if (window.document.documentMode) {
  // This is IE, use hashchange instead
  $(window).on('hashchange', onHistoryChange);
} else {
  $(window).on('popstate', onHistoryChange);
}
```

Comment: While using this in chrome I have observed one thing that on click of back button its capturing all previous event like if first time I click on back and then proceed to next page and again I came back it will call function 2 times, if I am clicking on back and coming again it is getting called 3 times. May I know is there any impact of this ?

Comment: I don't think this issue is related to this code as in chrome `hashchange` is not called at all only `popstate` is called, which exactly the same code as you had previously.

Comment: It's working as expected. need one more clarification on above point. Is there any way to stop above mentioned behaviour. like if I am clicking on back button, second time it will call this function 2 times, on third time again it will call the function 3 times. Is there any better way to avoid this ?

Comment: Could you please create a separate question for this, so that there is a separation of concern and future users can get specific answers for a specific issue while searching SO. and also explain the issue in details with some examples. Also, explain all browser details you tested this on.