# track back button event when coming back from third party page

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

How to track browser back button event in javascript when coming back from third party url.

If it is from the same host then we can use popstate (other than IE) or hashchange (for IE).

Basically I have to add new classes on browser back button when redirecting back to our application from third party url.

I have tried below reference answer but it is only valid when you are going back in same project.

reference - [back button event in same project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61570153/4286411)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set any flag and then when the page gets a load then again try to check it?

If not, you can give it a try.

For example, on the page, you use the **onbeforeunload** event and set the flag in the localstorage or in a cookie.

So the flag gets set before the page gets to unload.

Then when the user again opens the same page, you can check for the flag value on the onload event of the page and load your classes according to it.